# Cannot save Todo event on vTiger CRM 6.1

Tags: php, calendar, vtiger

I'm new to vtiger, I recently installed vTiger ver.6.1 and I noticed that whenever I tried to create a ToDo Event. nothing is saved.

Btw, I'm using MySQL.

I found this article here in Stack overflow:

> **[Vtiger: I can't add a To Do event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602796/vtiger-i-cant-add-a-to-do-event)**

but I think my problem is different from him. since he was using PostgreSQL and I'm using default.

another thing is, the OP mentioned a file:

> **TodoSave.php**

but when I checked my vtiger folder. there is no TodoSave.php file

Hope someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the log file.
If you don't know about debugging and logging, https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Developer_Debug_Techniques#PHP

Comment: I've been having the same issue and working on it right now. I'm going to activate full debug hooking into every single exception of php. I let you know.

Comment: I solved it by downloading the crm and installing PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5
turns out vTiger 6.1 does not support a lower version and the one I downloaded before is a test version

Answer (score 0):

The same issue, what i do is to update database to allow vtiger_activity_reminder_popup.status **null**